# a mysterious error in multiple symbolical integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages, special-functions

I am trying to do the following integration:

```
Ld = 2;
a1 = 0.3;
a2 = 1;    

potd[R_, z_] =
      -Integrate[(0.5/(2*a1)*Exp[-(Abs[z1]/a1)] + 
           0.5/(2*a2)*Exp[-(Abs[z1]/a2)])*
         Integrate[
          BesselK[0, a/Ld]*a*
           ArcSin[(2*a)/(
            Sqrt[(z - z1)^2 + (a + R)^2] + 
             Sqrt[(z - z1)^2 + (a - R)^2])], {a, 0, Infinity}, 
          GenerateConditions -> False], {z1, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
        GenerateConditions -> False];
```

then I evaluate the result for different pairs of `R`, `z`.

*Mathematica* complains that

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand a ArcSin[(2 a)/(Sqrt[Power[<<2>>]+Power[<<2>>]]+Sqrt[Power[<<2>>]+Power[<<2>>]])] BesselK[0,a/2] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{∞,0}}. >>

The point is that there is no `NIntegrate`: what does it mean?

I upload the function from my notebook so you can see that I am not using a `NIntegrate`.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it with `a1 = 3/10`?  It might help to indicate specific `R`, `z` that give the message.

Comment: @MichaelE2 that error shows up before I use any number.

Comment: Under some circumstances, which I cannot explain in this case, *Mathematica* will use numerical methods in symbolic calculations.  In this case, it seems to have to do with having approximate numeric coefficients, `0.5` and `a1`.  If they are changed to exact numbers `1/2` and `1/3`, the `NIntegrate` messages do not appear.  (FWIW, *M* tries to evaluate `NIntegrate[a ArcSin[(2 a)/(Sqrt[(a - R)^2 + (z - z1)^2] + Sqrt[(a + R)^2 + (z - z1)^2])] BesselK[0, a/2], {a, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 30.9546, AccuracyGoal -> ∞, PrecisionGoal -> 20.9546]`, which is foolish because `R` and `z` are symbols.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for the clarification ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved this problem.

The error message was due to the fact that *Mathematica* cannot perform the internal integration, so I split the two integrations and used `NIntegrate` instead of the symbolic integration:

```
p[z1_?NumericQ, R_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  -NIntegrate[
   BesselK[0, x/Ld]*x*
    ArcSin[(2*x)/(
     Sqrt[(z1)^2 + (x + 7.6)^2] + Sqrt[(z1)^2 + (x - 7.6)^2])], {x, 0,
     Infinity}];
potd[R_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(0.5/(2*a1)*Exp[-(Abs[z1]/a1)] + 
      0.5/(2*a2)*Exp[-(Abs[z1]/a2)])*p[z1, R, z], {z1, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}];
potd[7.6, 0]
```

with the result

> -1.77324

Still: I don't undersand the previous error since I wasn't using numeric integration, but now it works...